# Xubuntu 16.04 - simple scan not working with my scanner

Tags: xubuntu, canon, scanner, sane, xsane

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 and my scanner is a CanoScan LiDE 110.

Simple Scan is giving me a "unable to start scan" error and sometimes crashes when I attempt to scan again after being given the error.

I ran `lsusb` on the terminal:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04a9:1909 Canon, Inc. CanoScan LiDE 110
```

So I know my scanner is detected and I know my scanner isn't defected because it works on Windows XP running through VirtualBox, and I'm currently using that to scan.

Comment: Try to use Xsane .

Comment: I did, it gave me a I/O error.

Comment: Did you try gscan2pdf ? Install it from Terminal: `sudo apt-get install gscan2pdf`.

Comment: it gave me this: `gscan2pdf: sane_start: Error during device I/O`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Canon LiDE 25 only under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with all its versions (Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE) and

I finally found a solution by blacklisting the USB-ID. In fact, my scanner seemed to be detected as an HID device and not as a scanner and simple-scan returned a black page, or the scanner stopped during the scan, or the sensor didn't come back to its initial position.

So, I did the following:

1. In a terminal, type `lsusb` and find the USB-ID of your scanner (xxxx:xxxx). With my LiDE25, this command returned `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04a9:2220 Canon, Inc. CanoScan LIDE 25` so its USB-ID was 04a9:2220, for you, I think it will be `04a9:1909`,
2. Edit the config file `/etc/default/tlp` with the command:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/tlp
   ```

   and find the line (the 178th for me)

   ```
   USB_BLACKLIST=
   ```
3. Add your USB-ID (Example for my LiDE 25):

   ```
   USB_BLACKLIST=04a9:2220
   ```

   so for you, it will certainly be

   ```
   USB_BLACKLIST=04a9:1909
   ```
4. Save your file by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (the letter O, not zero)
5. Quit by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
6. Unplug your scanner and plug it in again without restarting your computer, you can try now.

This solution has worked for me; I hope it will for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Canon CanoScan LiDe 25 on Pop!_OS 18.04 lts. I simply disable "autosuspend usb" on TLP. Then it works good.

You can take a look at the [TLP config page](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#usb) for details.